# How to avoid space while concatenation if database values are null?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am concatenating three database values Firstname,middlename,lastname.Here is the Query -

```
Select ISNULL(t.FirstName,'')+' '+ISNULL(t.MiddleName,'')+' '+ ISNULL(t.LastName,'') as [UserName],Email from table1 t
```

I am getting null values for some middle names. Thats why I am getting extra spaces after concatenation.

**Firstname  LastName**   --getting two spaces at place of one

I want if middle name is null then only one space will be present in result.If it not null then there is one space between firstname, middlename and lastname.  I have tried some methods to avoid this but nothing worked.

Answer (score 5):

Put the space inside `ISNULL` function:

```
Select ISNULL(t.FirstName + ' ', '') 
    + ISNULL(t.MiddleName + ' ', '')
    + ISNULL(t.LastName,'') as [UserName]
```

Comment: nice, never thought of concatenating space with column value inside ISNULL.

Comment: Thanks for you help. But this is not working properly. when middle name is null it add space with null value.

Comment: @NeerajKumar, when t.MiddleName is null, ISNULL(t.MiddleName + ' ', '') results ''. Have you checked it?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin yes i Checked it.@Metal's Solution worked for me.

Comment: @NeerajKumar how is it that your code adds null with space? anything with null equals to null. (null + ' ' = null). this should work. here is the link https://rextester.com/PEZ63120

Answer (score 2):

you can use `replace()` function to replace double spaces to single space

```
Select replace(concat(coalesce(t.FirstName,''), ' '
    , coalesce(t.MiddleName,' ')
    , coalesce(t.LastName,''), '  ', ' ')) as [UserName]
    , Email 
from table1 t
```

Comment: @NeerajKumar, great! please don't forget to mark this answered.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `case when` clause

```
SELECT ISNULL(t.FirstName,'') + 
  CASE WHEN t.MiddleName IS NOT NULL THEN
    ' ' + t.MiddleName + ' '
  ELSE 
    ' ' 
  END +
  ISNULL(t.LastName,'') as [UserName],
  Email
FROM table1 t
```

Example [here](https://rextester.com/VSWCG96172)